# Bundle doesn't import gnuplot gem correctly; NameError: uninitialized constant thrown on access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have a module that lives in my Rails app as lib/render_graphs.rb. It looks like:

```
require 'gnuplot'
module RenderGraphs
  def render_standard_curve_graph(standard_curve, params, term = nil, output = nil)
    Gnuplot.open do |gp|
      # do things
    end
  end
end
if __FILE__ == $0
  include RenderGraphs
  render_standard_curve_graph(...)
end
```

If I invoke it on the command line with `ruby -r rubygems render_graphs.rb`, it works just fine. But if I try to call render_standard_curve_graph from my Rails app (I call it from a controller, which includes RenderGraphs) or from the Rails console, it gives an error like:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant RenderGraphs::Gnuplot
        from .../lib/render_graphs.rb:31:in `render_standard_curve_graph'
        from (irb):32
```

If I run `require '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/gnuplot-2.3.6/lib/gnuplot.rb'` at the Rails console before I call `render_standard_curve_graph`, it works just fine. What's wrong with `gem 'gnuplot'` in my Gemfile? `bundle show gnuplot` yields
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/gnuplot-2.3.6...

I am baffled. gnuplot is in my Gemfile and I've run bundle install and restarted the console (several times). Similar calls to other gems (GSL and roo) work just fine from other modules in my lib directory. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the GSL gem. The GSL gem must be loaded *after* the gnuplot gem, or else it prevents the Gnuplot module from appearing to the interpreter. Bundler does not support requiring gems in a particular order, so the fix that does not require modifying the gsl gem is to edit config/boot.rb and explicitly `require 'gnuplot'` immediately after `require 'rubygems'`, before Bundler is initialized.

Comment: I voted this up, but it doesn't actually work for me because I'm not using Rails. Would love to know how to make this work with Bundler in a regular Ruby project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to be explicit and always grab `Gnuplot` constant from the top level.
(When you run it on the command line, you are including `RenderGraphs` into top level,
and `render_standard_curve_graph` is able to look up Gnuplot at that level.)

```
module RenderGraphs
  def render_standard_curve_graph(standard_curve, params, term = nil, output = nil)
    ::Gnuplot.open do |gp|
      # do things
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! It still doesn't like me, though now the error message has changed to 'uninitialized constant Gnuplot' instead of RenderGraphs::Gnuplot. http://pastebin.com/7skVp2D6 (The line number reference has changed because I moved code around, but it's the same `::Gnuplot.open do |gp|` line.) Requiring 'gnuplot' doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. Data science is so hard.

I had code like

```
require "gsl"
# prepare data
# ...
require "gnuplot"
# plot data
# ...
```

And I was getting `NameError: uninitialized constant Gnuplot`

I Turned it into

```
require "gnuplot"
require "gsl"
# prepare data
# ...
# plot data
# ...
```

And the error was gone.